# VBS script to retrieve user information from Azure Active Directory

Tags: powershell, azure, vbscript, active-directory

This may not even be possible without powershell (or Azure Powershell), but can I use a script to retrieve user information from AZURE active directory on a Windows 10 computer?
Since the user has already provided credentials and the user name has been pulled down from Azure, is there any other information pulled down that I can reference as a system object (for eg).
Example of code to show user name:

Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")

wScript.Echo objSysInfo.UserName

I want to see other information such as users department(i.e. .department , so that I can map drives by identifying the users department rather than using the user name).

If I can't use vbs then is this possible with Azure powershell without re-entering user credentials and/or re-verifying user credentials?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with Azure PowerShell commandlets:

```
Connect-MsolService -CurrentCredential
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName username@domain
```